# Maximum possible connected component by removing hyperplanes form $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, connectedness

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ be 4 hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^3$ then How many maximum possible connected component are present in $\mathbb R^3$ after removing these 4 hyperplane

I can visuallise that if i remove 3 hyperplanes then maximum 8 connected component present.

I donot able to visualise for 4 hyperplanes .

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: See [cake number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_number), the number for 4 planes is 15. There is an animation for this 4->15 configuration in above wiki entry.

Comment: Why hyper?$\;\!$

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, this is akin to removing three lines from $\Bbb R^2$, where
you can get at most seven planar regions.

Consider a tetrahedron $T$ in $\Bbb R^3$.
By removing the four planes forming the boundary of $T$ one gets fifteen regions
remaining.

Let's consider what happens when we remove the fourth plane $P$ in the general
case. Before then there are at most eight regions. We claim we can gain
at most seven regions at this stage. The earlier planes meet $P$ in
at most three lines. These lines divide the plane $P$ into at most seven
plane regions. But these plane regions correspond to regions in $\Bbb R^3$
that are split in two by the fourth hyperplane: the number of regions gained
by the fourth plane is the number of plane regions the lines divide
$P$ into, and is at most seven.

Comment: Nice Solution Sir. I counted for tetrahedron that there are 13 component outside and 4 component inside tetrahedorn .SO there are 17 total connected component? Is this true